# Toggle between selected radio button using D3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Consider I have 4 radio buttons as in html

```
<form id="form">
    <input type="radio" name="stack" value="north">north<br>
    <input type="radio" name="stack" value="east" >east<br>
    <input type="radio" name="stack" value="west">west<br>
    <input type="radio" name="stack" value="south">south
</form>
```

How do I get the value of selected radio button and assign onto a global variable, on selection , using D3.js ,such a way I can toggle between selections?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If those are the *only*  inputs you have, you can do:

```
d3.selectAll("input").on("change", function(){
    console.log(this.value)
});
```

To select only that specific group of radio buttons, use their `name`:

```
d3.selectAll("input[name='stack']").on("change", function(){
    console.log(this.value)
});
```

To assign it to a global (declaring without `var`):

```
d3.selectAll("input[name='stack']").on("change", function(){
    globalVariable = this.value;
});
```

Here is the demo:

```js
d3.selectAll(("input[name='stack']")).on("change", function(){
console.log(this.value)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<form id="form">
    <input type="radio" name="stack" value="north">north<br>
    <input type="radio" name="stack" value="east" >east<br>
    <input type="radio" name="stack" value="west">west<br>
    <input type="radio" name="stack" value="south">south
</form>
```

Comment: That's perfect. Could you also add how do you assign the result to a global variable?

Comment: @Lalitha just set the variable to `this.value`: https://jsfiddle.net/ry71kwu2/ . Or declare it without `var`.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ry71kwu2/4/     I need the result outside d3.select but doesn't happen.

Comment: That's because you're logging the variable *before* the user clicking any button. In JavaScript, that code will run immediately, and you're getting the value of the variable when the program runs the first time. For instance, see this fiddle, where I do the console.log every second. Click the buttons and you'll see. https://jsfiddle.net/Lgonp3wb/

Comment: Yes, I understand it. But I need to use that value for a scenario similar to this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/Lgonp3wb/3/  It is my ultimate need.

Comment: It will simply not work! You'll need to write a code that gets the value of the radio button *when the user clicks the radio button*, and then pass that value to whatever function you want.

Comment: The purpose of this is, on based on selection in radio, different charts are getting rendered.

Comment: It doesn't change what I just wrote. This is what you have to do: https://jsfiddle.net/ojtL1p88/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130288/discussion-between-lalitha-and-gerardo-furtado).